# <customErrors mode="Off"/> error?

Tags: sharepoint-server, error

I was changing a page in SharePoint, when suddenly, I got the following error:

> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current
>   custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the
>   application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons).
>   It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server
>   machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within
>   a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This  tag should then have its
>   "mode" attribute set to "Off".
>
> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a
>   custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's  configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.

What could be the reason of this error?

Answer (score 2):

This is a general error message . to show the actual error :

- From IIS websites  select your website
- Right click and select explore
- Then open the (web.config) of your site
  -Search for "customerrors" and set its mode to "off" and save the file

After applying this steps run the page again so you can see the actual error and can trace it.

Answer (score 1):

Additional settings need to update based on [Mohamed Ragab](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/44122/mohamed-ragab)'s Steps.

You could check below thread for details.

While you could find more detailed errors in ULS log(path:C:\Program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14 or 15 based on different version\LOGS) usually.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6171.sharepoint-2010-modify-web-config-to-display-error-details.aspx